# I want to implement cordova-plugin-googlemaps in PhoneGap Build cloud service

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I followed this link - https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps - but didn't understand what to do. How do I implement cordova-plugin-googlemaps in PhoneGap Build cloud service?

Comment: did you obtained android and ios API key before installing plugin ?

Comment: can you please suggest how to get ios key

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/get-api-key Refer this.